# awk array: count column return line

Tags: multidimensional-array, awk

I have tried several awk arrays but just can´t get my head around it.
Having a file with 4 colums the awk skript should count for each line how many times the value in column 2 appears.

*Input File*

```
A1^ABC^173^2012
A2^BDK^153^2013
A3^AFD^223^2012
B1^ABC^083^1999
B2^KLX^033^2012
B3^ABC^593^2003 
B4^KLX^323^2001
```

So as result I want to print the counter for the value in column 2 at the end of each line. E.g line one has value "ABC" in column2. "ABC" appears 3 times in the entire file and is printed at the end of the line.

*Output File*

```
A1^ABC^173^2012^3
A2^BDK^153^2013^1
A3^AFD^223^2012^1
B1^ABC^083^1999^3
B2^KLX^033^2012^2
B3^ABC^593^2003^3
B4^KLX^323^2001^2
```

Hope anyone got an idea on how to solve it.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="^" } FNR==NR { a[$2]++; next } { print $0, a[$2] }' file.txt{,}
```

Results:

```
A1^ABC^173^2012^3
A2^BDK^153^2013^1
A3^AFD^223^2012^1
B1^ABC^083^1999^3
B2^KLX^033^2012^2
B3^ABC^593^2003^3
B4^KLX^323^2001^2
```

Comment: What does the `{,}` do?

Comment: @Jotne Takes the input file twice, try `echo file{,}`.

Comment: Ahh, a new one for me, thanks :) -- `{,,,}` repeat it three times

Comment: +1 for the approach, I was just going to suggest `awk -F'^' 'NR==FNR{s[$2]++;next} {print $0 FS s[$2]} ' file file`. I've never seen that `{,}` notation - is that bash-specifc?

Comment: @EdMorton https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

Comment: @sudo_O Thanks. ANy idea if other shells support it or if it's just bash?

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks Ed; good question! Please see the 'portability' section [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BraceExpansion).

Answer (score 3):

The buffered approach:

```
awk -F'^' -v OFS='^' '{a[NR]=$0;c[$2]++}
    END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){split(a[i],b);print a[i],c[b[2]]}}' file
```

Output:

```
A1^ABC^173^2012^3
A2^BDK^153^2013^1
A3^AFD^223^2012^1
B1^ABC^083^1999^3
B2^KLX^033^2012^2
B3^ABC^593^2003^3
B4^KLX^323^2001^2
```

To store the output in a new file use the redirection operator:

```
awk -F'^' -v OFS='^' '{a[NR]=$0;c[$2]++}
    END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){split(a[i],b);print a[i],c[b[2]]}}' file > outfile
```

Comment: +1 very good answer, trust me I hadn't seen this while making mine work.

Comment: works fine, many thanks. But I´m actually not getting the split and following print section. what is 'b' doing?